# MAMP multiple virtualhosts not working

Tags: wordpress, apache, mamp, hosts, virtual-hosts

Somehow my virtualhosts won't work and give me The requested URL / was not found on this server. I have tried multiple things, but can't get it to work. My MAMP root folder is set to the Projects folder

I have the following folder structure:

```
-Projects
   -website1
   -websites
      -public
      -system
         -website2
```

What I want is website1 to work on a different URL than website 2. What I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/myname/Documents/Projects/websites/system/%-3"
    ServerAlias *.system.test
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8888>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/myname/Documents/Projects/websites/public/%-3"
    ServerAlias *.public.test
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8888>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/myname/Documents/Projects/website1"
    ServerAlias test.nl
</VirtualHost>
```

the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1    website2.system.test
127.0.0.1    test.nl
```

I have also tried:

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
        VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/myname/Documents/Projects/%-3"
        ServerAlias *.test.nl
    </VirtualHost>
```

Nothing seems to work to get website1 (wordpress website) working under test.nl any ideas? The reason why I have that folder structure is because "websites" is for work and the root for private projects. BTW whenever I put website1 in the system folder and add : website1.public.test to the hosts file it works, however when I put it in the public folder it doesnt, it looks like the only virtualhost read is the top one?

Comment: You need [ServerName](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servername) directives in your vhost config sections.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a fix: [Apache 2 only serves first virtual host](http://alexking.org/blog/2007/11/01/apache-2-only-serves-first-virtual-host)